# How to update a large amount of records in SQL Azure everyday

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a table where i have to update more then 10K records everyday. This takes a lot of time when using a simple update statement. Is there a faster way in SQL azure to batch update records?

regards
Dieter

Comment: what performance tier are you on? 10K records isn't a whole lot but if the row sizes are big and you're on basic or one of the lower end standard tiers, you might be running into perf limits, specifically on the transaction log (usually first to go).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure is not radically different with exception of few things.when a query is slow ,you have to consider so many factors same like OnPremises .Below is the way you can start troubleshooting..

> 1.) whether there are any locking/Blockings

```
select blocking_session_id,wait_type,wait_time,last_Wait_type
 from sys.dm_exec_requests qs
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle)
```

It depends on from where you are trying to do Bulk load,above query should show help you in detemining  in what is the wait type,is it network,DTU..

> 2.) While working with Azure DBs,you have to conisder one more factor called DTUS(simply put how much of transactions you can run per second).

you can use below query to see if your tier is choking ..

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

if you wait type in first query is disk,ram,IO and DTU query consistently shows DTU percent  >90,then you may need to upgrade your database tier too or consider tuning queries

If none of the above helps,you can also post your execution plan tooo